# or takes two values arguments haskell

Tags: haskell, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am a beginner in haskell and I tried to define a simple function for Sieve of Eratosthenes but it says
error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool -> Bool’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
    • The function ‘or’ is applied to two value arguments,
        but its type ‘t Bool -> Bool’ has only one
      In the expression: or (mod n x) (divl l x)
      In an equation for ‘divl’: divl (n : l) x = or (mod n x) (divl l x)
   |
13 | divl (n:l) x = or (mod n x) (divl l x)
```

```
erat l [] = l
erat l (x:t) = if divl l x then erat l t else erat (x:t) l

divl (n:l) x = or (mod n x) (divl l x)
divl [] x = True
```

I tried to write that as an operator with "`" but nothing worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`or` is not the boolean OR operator; that's `(||)`. `or` takes a list (well, `Foldable`) of Boolean values and returns `True` if at least one value is `True`.

```
> or []
False
> or [True, False]
True
```

(Note that `or []` is defined to be `False` to preserve the identity `or xs || or ys == or (xs ++ ys)`. As a concrete example, `or [] || or [False] == or [False]`.)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` instead of `or :: Foldable t => t Bool -> Bool`

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-124--124-

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:or

i.e. `mod n x || divl l x` or `or [mod n x, divl l x]`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the modulo is zero, or one of the remaining, you use [**`(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-124--124-):

```
divl (n:l) x = mod n x == 0 || divl l x
divl [] x = False
```

The basecase should be `False`, otherwise it will always return `True`. It is probably better to work with `any` however:

```
divl ls x = any ((0 ==) . (`mod` x)) ls
```

Comment: it gives me back the list itself

Comment: @LeonardoRosati: did you change the second clause to `= False`?

Comment: @ WillemVanOnsem yes i did

Answer (score 1):

at the end summarizing the answers i resolved

```
erat :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
erat l [] = l
erat l (x:t) = if divl l x then erat l t else erat (x:l) t

divl (n:l) x = ((mod x n) == 0) || (divl l x)
divl [] x = False
```